# Emoji keyboard online for browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory, memory-management

I wrote an emoji keyboard online (maybe called it emoji picker, emoji selector) at https://www.emojionline.org. Everything works ok, but there is one problem for memory optimization. My data is stored in an json file. It has 2000 records (size 600kb). I use ajax to load it into memory:

```
function loadData(){
json = (function () {
json = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': 'data.json',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data;
    }
});
return json;
})();
```

}
And on ready event of document, I called it.

```
$(document).read(function(e){var data = loadData();});
```

Everything works well on PC, Mac and smartphone with high RAM (>=GB). For weaker devices, I feel it works bad. Sometime, if the connection is low, I got the message ".... the page need to be reloaded".
I understand that to hold a big json file in memory is not good processing. But I need this data for processing. What can I do to do in this situation? I just use jquery, js, html, css. No dynamic languages for web, such as PHP, Java... in this situation are recommended.

I found the solution, but I don't know this is good or not. For me, it really reduce time loading. The solution is: embbed the data into html file. Use external files always make more requests and reduce performance.

Comment: Use [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) concept. Instead of loading everything. Load as per the user's need.